# How can I move (or create another) publish button?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, metabox, publish

How do I create a "publish" button to put in a custom metabox?

Or if you can point me to the code that creates the current publish box, that'd help me out.

-attempting to simplify my custom post type-

Comment: Apparently you can just copy and paste the HTML from the major-publishing-actions div but you lose some javascript interaction as the page tries to reload instantly (even though it posts on reload) instead of working the ajax (with the spiny wheel next to publish). Still looking for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dig in Core

All admin UI pages use a core function for a reason:

```
submit_button( $text = NULL, $type = 'primary', $name = 'submit', $wrap = true, $other_attributes = NULL );
```

There's also `get_submit_button()` in case you want to return instead of print the button.

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="submit">Your Text</button>` should about do it for you...it's just a submit button, nothing special. It's generated by `post_submit_meta_box()`, specifically `submit_button( __( 'Publish' ), 'primary', 'publish', false, array( 'tabindex' => '5', 'accesskey' => 'p' ) );`.

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks for the PHP code there. Any idea how to include the original AJAX functionality?

Comment: I'd guess it's tied to the class or the ID, here's the html `<input type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" class="button-primary" value="Publish" tabindex="5" accesskey="p">` Mimic that exactly and see if you can get it to just WORK, then start working backwards and see if you can find the source of what makes it work...probably be a heck of a lot faster than digging through all the JS lol...if I had to take a hack, I'd say that its #publish that does it.